# Java remove duplicates from linked list

Tags: java

I want to remove duplicates from sorted linked list {0 1 2 2 3 3 4 5}.

`

```
public Node removeDuplicates(Node header)
{
    Node tempHeader = null;
    if(header != null) 
        tempHeader = header.next;
    else return header;
    Node prev = header;
    if((tempHeader == null)) return header ;

    while(tempHeader != null)
    {
        if(tempHeader.data != prev.data)
        {
            prev.setNext(tempHeader);
        }
    tempHeader = tempHeader.next;
    }
    prev = header;
    printList(prev);
    return tempHeader;
}
```

`

prev.setNext(tempHeader) is not working correctly inside the while loop. Ideally when prev = 2 and tempHeader = 3, prev.next should be node with data = 3.

Printlist function just takes header pointer and prints the list.

Node definition is given below.

```
public class Node
{
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it with the [homework] tag.

Comment: Is this homework or why don't you use java.util.*

Comment: No, this is not homework. I found one PDF on stanford website which contains 18 linked list problems and one of them is removeDuplicate program. here is the link; http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/105/LinkedListProblems.pdf

Comment: You are not calling prev.next anywhere. You are just calling prev.setNext(tempHeader) inside while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is sorted, so you know that duplicates are going to sit next to each other. If you want to edit the list in place then, you've got to have two list pointers (which you do). The one you call tempHeader and prev, and you've got to advance them both in the the list as you go (which I don't see in the code). Otherwise, if you don't advance the prev pointer as you go, then you're always comparing the element under tempHeader to the first item in the list, which is not correct.

An easier way to do this, however, is to build a new list as you go. Simply remember the value of the last item that you appended to the list. Then if the one that you're about to insert is the same then simply don't insert it, and when you're done, just return your new list.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you 2 suggestions for the above suggestion
1) Convert the linked List to Set, that will eliminate the duplicates and
Back from Set to the Linked list
Code to get this done would be

```
linkedList = new LinkedList<anything>(new HashSet<anything>(origList));
```

2) You can use LinkedHashSet, if you dont want any duplicates

Comment: that sounds good but can we do the way I am trying to do. I think, we can do in C/C++ this way. Isn't so?

Comment: -1: This completely ignores the fact that the list is sorted, AND requires sorting afterwards (unless, of course, you use LinkedHashSet, but either way it is way more expensive than a single linear pass).

Answer (score 1):

In this case no return value is needed.

```
public void removeDuplicates(Node list) {
    while (list != null) {
        // Walk to next unequal node:
        Node current = list.next;
        while (current != null && current.data.equals(list.data)) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        // Skip the equal nodes:
        list.next = current;
        // Take the next unequal node:
        list = current;

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This will do the job, except current.data.equals(list.data) should change to current.data == list.data

Answer (score 1):

```
public ListNode removeDuplicateElements(ListNode head) {
  if (head == null || head.next == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (head.data.equals(head.next.data)) {
        ListNode next_next = head.next.next;
        head.next = null;
        head.next = next_next;
        removeDuplicateElements(head);
    } else {
        removeDuplicateElements(head.next);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By DoublyLinked List and using HashSet,

```
  public static void deleteDups(Node n) {
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Node previous = null;
    while (n != null) {
        if (set.contains(n.data)) {
            previous.next = n.next;
        } else {
            set.add(n.data);
            previous = n;
        }
        n = n.next;
    }
}
```

doublylinkedList

```
class Node{

public Node next;
public Node prev;
public Node last;
public int data;
public Node (int d, Node n, Node p) {
    data = d;
    setNext(n);
    setPrevious(p);
}

public Node() { }

public void setNext(Node n) {
    next = n;
    if (this == last) {
        last = n;
    }
    if (n != null && n.prev != this) {
        n.setPrevious(this);
    }
}

public void setPrevious(Node p) {
    prev = p;
    if (p != null && p.next != this) {
        p.setNext(this);
    }
}}
```