# Deleting duplicates from a Linked List

Tags: java

I am trying to delete duplicates from a Linked List. However, the method that I wrote causes an infinite loop and I'm not sure why there is one. Here is my method:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Question {
    public static void deleteDupsB(LinkedListNode n) {
        LinkedListNode runner = null;
        LinkedListNode previous = null;
        while(n != null) {
            runner = n.next;
            while(runner != null) {
                if(n.data == runner.data) {
                    previous.next = runner.next; //This line is causing an infinite loop and I'm not sure why.
                }
                else {
                    previous = runner; 
                }
                runner = runner.next;
            }
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        LinkedListNode first = new LinkedListNode(0, null, null); //AssortedMethods.randomLinkedList(1000, 0, 2);
        LinkedListNode head = first;
        LinkedListNode second = first;
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            second = new LinkedListNode(i % 2, null, null);
            first.setNext(second);
            second.setPrevious(first);
            first = second;
        }


        System.out.println(head.printForward());
        // LinkedListNode clone = head.clone();
        deleteDupsB(head);
        System.out.println(head.printForward());
        // deleteDupsC(clone);
        // System.out.println(clone.printForward());
    }
}
```

I know there are some problems with it such as `runner` throwing an exception eventually. But I guess I'm not too worried about that right now. I think the method is kind of producing the effect because when I insert a `break` inside of first `while` loop and the `second`, it deletes all the 0s. Anyhow, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643790/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list)

Comment: I think `previous.next = runner.next;` runs into adress 0 because `previous` is null at the first run. I wonder why no memory access fault occured.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your object's `equals(Object)` method is sound, then copy the `LinkedList` to a `LinkedHashSet`.  Better yet, if you need to eliminate duplicates, just use the `LinkedHashSet` instead of the `LinkedList`.

Comment: I don't think he's allowed to use those classes, since this is obviously for school.

Comment: Haha... yea... well, it is not for school but I'm studying from an interview book. And one of the questions was this...

Answer (score 0):

May be reason in the next code line:

```
for(...) {
    ...
    first = second;
}
```

You should use "first = second" only in case if your list contains 1 element only.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using streams. It's probably less efficient, but it's less error prone and it saves a lot of time.

```
LinkedListNode list = ...;
list.stream()
    // This removes duplicates
    .distinct()
    // And this turns it back into a linked list
    .collect((Supplier<LinkedList<Integer>>) LinkedList::new, 
                LinkedList::add, 
                (left, right) -> {
                  left.addAll(right);
                }
            );
```