# Can we bring back the last element's pointer in linked list to the first element?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am writing a code to remove duplicates from the linked list. Code is mentioned below :

Here I am creating the set and inserting all the node's data. If it returns true i.e. element is not present in set and was not added previously to Set it'll add the node's data within that set else the corresponding data's node reference from previous node will be removed and shifts the head pointer to next node. After coming out of while loop, we have head pointing the last element. If I display it then it only displays last element not duplicate removed list. How to put head pointer again to starting node from last node so that I can print the Linked List?

```
    final Node ref = head;
    final Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

    /*
     * while (null != head.next) { final Node rn = head.next; if (!s.add(head.next.data)) { if (null !=
     * head.next.next) { head.next = head.next.next; } } head = rn; }
     */
    while (null != head.next) {
        // final Node rn = head.next;
        if (!s.add(head.data)) {
            if (null != head.next) {
                head = head.next;
            }
        }
        head = head.next;
    }
    final boolean b1 = s.add(head.data);
    if (b1 == false) {
        head = null;
    }
    head = ref;
    return head;
```

Comment: The answer to your question is trivial: set head equal to ref (which you used to save head, assume that was the original head). But this code is nowhere near working. Please learn to use a debugger and step through to see what is happening and that will help you understand how it works.

Comment: There is a question already like this: [remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643790/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list)

Answer (score 1):

You have already taken the reference of the head Node in Node variable ref, and you have used head Node for traversing, so just return Node variable ref in the end. It will give you the desired result considering the rest of the code is correct.

Try this:

```
    final Node ref = head;
    final Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

    /*
     * while (null != head.next) { final Node rn = head.next; if (!s.add(head.next.data)) { if (null !=
     * head.next.next) { head.next = head.next.next; } } head = rn; }
     */
    while (null != head.next) {
        // final Node rn = head.next;
        if (!s.add(head.data)) {
            if (null != head.next) {
                head = head.next;
            }
        }
        head = head.next;
    }
    final boolean b1 = s.add(head.data);
    if (b1 == false) {
        head = null;
    }

    return ref;
```

Remove head=ref!

Or if you want to use set for removing duplicates from the Linked List, you can use LinkedHashSet, LinkedHashSet maintains the order of Insertion, the approach is given below:

```
        if(head==null)
            return null;

        Node n = head;
        LinkedHashSet<Integer> lSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        while(n.next!=null){
            lSet.add(n.data);
            n = n.next;
        }

        lSet.add(n.data);

        Iterator<Integer> it = lSet.iterator();

        Node newHead = new Node(it.next());

        Node listNodes = newHead;

        while(it.hasNext()){
            listNodes.next = new Node(it.next());
            listNodes = listNodes.next;

        }

        return newHead;
```