# Remove Duplicates from Linked List

Tags: java

So I have a linked list that I am trying to remove duplicates from.

My basic algorithm that I thought up is to pretty much use the runner technique. Where I keep two pointers to compare adjacent elements. If they are the same I change the pointer of p1 to point to p1.next.next if not I keep traversing the list. However I keep getting a null pointer exception in the solution I have typed.

```
Node RemoveDuplicates(Node head) {
  // This is a "method-only" submission. 
  // You only need to complete this method. 
    if (head == null){
        return null;
    } 

        Node current = head;
    Node runner = head;



    while(current != null && runner != null && runner.next != null){
    runner = runner.next;
    if(runner.data == current.data){
        if(current.next != null){
                    current = current.next.next; 

        }
    }else{
        current = current.next;
    }
}



    return current;
}
```

At the point that I exit the while loop current is null. Which I think is the problem. How would I return the head of the altered list.

Comment: Why not just use a `Set` to forbid duplicates? Is it necessary to maintain the order of items as they were inserted into your collection?

Comment: That was my initial thought to use a set but there are already sorted

Comment: and the output looks like it remains in that sorted order

Comment: I typically use a set when it is not sorted..But maybe it doesn't matter

Comment: `current.next.next` could be `null`

Comment: How about a `LinkedHashSet` which gives you the benefits of a `Set` and a `List`? See [LinkedHashSet in Oracle JDK 8 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: also I wanted to try and do it using pointers seeing as I will need to know this for other linked list problems

Comment: @Bobulous i have to return a node

Comment: If your list isn't yuge you could walk to the end using recursion and as the stack unwinds you'd check if the `next` was a dup and if so return it thereby removing the one in the current frame.

Comment: is recursion really needed for this problem though? @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: `current.next` could be `null` therefore accessing `current.next.next` could cause a null pointer exception. Please enclose `current = current.next.next;` within `if ( current.next != null)` and try running your code.

Comment: I still get a null pointer exception

Comment: see edits please @SreedevShibu

Comment: @BoJackson try replacing `return current;` with `return head;`

Comment: Needed? No, but it leads to cleaner code than loops and conditionals, less than 10 readable lines.

Comment: mind showing an example @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: @SreedevShibu just printed out the regular list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643790/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list)

Comment: I think finded, you can look from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459557/java-remove-duplicates-from-linked-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to return head at the end, so that you are returning the list, not just the last element.
Second thing, you'll want to modify the .next references instead of assigning them in some of the cases.

Note this doesn't work if the list isn't sorted.

Before: 1 1 3 3 
After: 1 3

This code works (and I've tested it)

```
static Node RemoveDuplicates(Node head) {
    if (head == null) return null;

    Node current = head;
    Node runner = head;

    while (current != null && current.next != null) {
        runner = current.next;
        while (runner != null && runner.data == current.data) {
            current.next = runner.next; // skip the repeat
            runner = runner.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: okay it works. But is there a way to do it without two while loops?

Comment: I don't think so, as you'll need to keep advancing the runner until it doesn't see a duplicate

Comment: ah okay thanks man I am really trying to get a firm understanding of all this pointer magic

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=5075 this link does it in one while loop

Comment: @BoJackson My initial assumption would be that the above code given by Zach would work for an unsorted linked list, while the code provided within that link only works for sorted linked lists. Very often, sorting an iterable reduces the complexity of operations on that iterable.

Answer (score 2):

OK, although you've already accepted an answer, here's some example code using recursion to remove the dups from an ordered list per your request in the comments. (if your list isn't ordered, order it :) )

```
public Node removeDups(Node root) {
    if (root.next == null)
        return root;
    root.next = removeDups(root.next);
    if (root.data == root.next.data)
        return root.next;
    return  root;
} // call as root = removeDups(root);
```

As you mentioned, recursion isn't really necessary here but you're using a Node-based linked list which is recursively defined. So, when it makes sense, the elegance of the solution has its benefits.

What I like about it is that you're not doing any `node.next.next` or needing to check for that `null` case. Once the stack starts unwinding, you're already in a position to start checking for dups. Then it's just a matter of comparing `root.data` and `root.next.data`; both of which you already know exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with single traversal with 2 pointer.and also this code works with single while loop.

```
public Node deleteDuplicates(Node head) {
        Node current=head;
            if (head == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
             Node runner=head.next;
               while(head.next!=null && runner!=null)
                {
                    if(head.val == runner.val)
                       prev=runner.next;
                    else
                    {
                      head.next=runner;
                      head=head.next;
                      prev=runner.next;
                    }
                }
                head.next=runner;
            }
            return current; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single traversal. Just maintain two pointers temp 
and next_of_next. Make temp iterate for each node and when the data of temp and the next node is equal, point next_of_next to the alternate node after temp and delete the node after temp.

```
Node removeDuplicates(Node head)
{
    Node temp = head;
    Node next_of_next;
    if (head == null)    
        return;
    while (temp.next != null) 
    {
        if (temp.data == temp.next.data) 
        {
            next_of_next = temp.next.next;
            temp.next = null;
            temp.next = next_of_next;
        }
        else 
           temp = temp.next;
    }
return head ;
}
```

Comment: You can refer here too for more details - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-a-sorted-linked-list/

Answer (score 0):

Here an apporach without recursion using a `HashSet`:

```
public void RemoveDuplicates()
{
    if (head != null)
    {
        var hm = new HashSet<T>();
        Node current = head;
        Node prev = null;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (!hm.Contains(current.Value))
            {
                hm.Add(current.Value);
                prev = current;
                current = current.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                prev.Next = current.Next;
                current = prev.Next;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```